# SQL syntax error on INSERT

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I keep running into an error from the following statement:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT into financial_statements (url) 
                  VALUES (%s) WHERE provider=%s AND date=%s""", (url, provider, date))
```

The error I get is:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'WHERE provider='ANGEL' AND date='2012-03-01'' at line 2")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a WHERE clause for an INSERT statement.

Maybe you meant to perform an UPDATE?

```
UPDATE financial_statements
SET url = %s
WHERE provider=%s AND date=%s
```

Comment: Ahh, forgot about that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to use `WHERE` in an `INSERT` statement - there is nothing to restrict.

If you want to modify an existing row, use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE financial_statements SET url=%s WHERE provider=%s and DATE=%s
```